# Change the value of Author field

Tags: list, splistitem, spfielduser

I am copying over items from one list to another list.

After copying the "Author" field gets populated with "System Account" and so I wish to update some fields in the destination list as follows.

I have a list with a custom Person column named "OriginalAuthor".

I want to replace the value of built-in "Author" with the value of "OriginalAuthor".

I also wish to achieve the same with the modified field (which currently DOES work)

I found a few examples on-line but could not get any to work. So far I have the following:

```
foreach (SPListItem destItem in destList.Items)
{
     SPFieldUserValue val = new SPFieldUserValue(web.Site.RootWeb, destItem["OriginalAuthor"].ToString());

     destItem["Author"] = val;
     destItem["Modified"] = destItem["OriginalModified"];
     destItem.Update();
}
destList.Update();
```

The modified date gets replaced however, the Author field remains the same.

How can I get this to work?

thanks,
KS

Comment: `destItem["Author"] = destItem["OriginalAuthor"]`, this doesn't work? if OriginalAuthor is Person field too, it should!

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought - but it just doesnt work.

Comment: Perplexed, [have a look at this URL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/14/can-we-update-the-values-of-created-by-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx), do read at the end of the post - where it says it will not update created by field but posted a workaround by a friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after being unable to accomplish this I have decided to use Sharepoint Content Manager to copy the items which preserves the required fields. Thanks to all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't grab the Author field from the original item?

My other thought has to do with using [SPListItem.SystemUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx) instead of Update(), but that has more to do with not changing Modified/Modified By than Author.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but as suspected it stopped me from updating the modified date and it didnt affect the Author field either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and I cannot test it right now, but i think author field is a person field, so you cannot just put a name there, i think it should be an spuser or maybe some other type which references to user in SP.

Or you can also try this code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["myList"];
list.Fields["Author"].ReadOnlyField = false;
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
item["Author"] = "value";
item.SystemUpdate(false);
list.Fields["Author"].ReadOnlyField = true;
```

Happy coding